# Converting Chrome app manifest from V1 to v2

Tags: json, google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I have made a chrome app in manifest version 1 with the code :

```
 {
"name": "J-Tech",
"version": "2",
"icons": { "128": "icon.png" },
"app": {
"urls": [
"http://www.j-tech-web.co.uk"
],
"launch": {
"web_url": "http://www.j-tech-web.co.uk"
}
}
}
```

I can't find a tutorial to make it take me the my website, can anyone tell me how

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
     {
    "name": "J-Tech",
    "description": "sample Text",
    "version": "2",
    "manifest_version": "2",
    "icons": 
    {
        "128": "icon.png"
    },

    "app":
    {
        "urls": 
    [
            "http://www.j-tech-web.co.uk"
        ],

        "launch": 
    {
            "web_url": "http://www.j-tech-web.co.uk"
        }
    },

    "permissions": 
    [

    ]
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit what was the error and why your code fixes it.